# Special characters with Ajax and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, encoding, utf-8

I have a MySQL database encoded with the default characterset UTF8. I have also a PHP code encoded with the same charset `meta charset="UTF-8"`.

My connection to the database is configured to use UTF8 too

```
new PDO("mysql:host=" .$host. ";dbname=".$database,$username,$password,
        array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

But I have a problem when I use **Ajax** to get the content of a textbox and insert it into the database.

If I do not use special characters it works fine but when I use a quote or something everything stops working.

I tried to use [UTF8_encode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-encode.php) and [UTF8_decode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-decode.php) but nothing changed

### EDIT

PHP

```
...
<meta charset="UTF-8">
...
<textarea class="commentBox"  id="<?php echo $id_case;?>"></textarea>
<button class="saveComment" id="<?php echo $id_case;?>"> Save comment </button>

//id_case is different for each textarea
```

Javascript

```
$('.saveComment').click(function() 
        {   
            var idComment = this.id;
            var content = $('#'+idComment+'.commentBox').val();
            add_comment(idComment, content);
        });

function add_comment(case_id, content)
{           
    $.post("../functions/ajax/add_comment.php",
    {
      id_case: case_id,
      content: content
    },
    function(data,status)
    {       
        alert("It worked !");
        console.log("Function add_comment : "+status);
    });             
}
```

add_comment.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id_case'], $_POST['content']))
    {       
        $case = $_POST['id_case'];  
        $content = $_POST['content'];   
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error during sending data to [add_comment.php]";
    }   

    if($db != null)
    {       
        try
            {
                $sql = ("UPDATE cases SET progress_remarks = '$content' WHERE id_cases = $case");               
                $result = $db->exec($sql);  

                echo $content;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
            }   

    }

    else echo "Erreur interne (fill_progress.php)";
?>
```

My database connection is done somewhere else but looks like this

```
$this->con = new PDO("mysql:host=" .$host. ";dbname=".$database,$username,$password,
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Comment: use addslashes in php or escap string of mysql

Comment: Please share the code that fails.

Comment: If you're using a *quote*...!? Mightn't you think it has something to do with this: `SET .. = '$content'`? Quotes... Quotes in quotes... Hmmmmmmm... [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I use a quote or something everything stops working.

It is unclear whether the problem is (1) just an escaping issue, or (2) also a utf8 issue.

Since PDO has a builtin way to take care of escaping, use it:

```
$sql = ("UPDATE cases SET progress_remarks = ? WHERE id_cases = $case");
$result = $db->exec($sql, $content);
```

This is probably the preferred way to set the charset with PDO: `$db = new PDO('dblib:host=host;dbname=db;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pwd);`

`meta charset="UTF-8"` refers to the  tag in HTML, not PHP or MySQL.

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- Is the column in question declared `CHARACTER SET utf8`?

Comment: The database default collation and characterset were declared utf8 but the table itself were not. That was the mistake